# Function calling and return statement

Tags: c++, function, return

In the given C++ code when the statement n isn't present the function abc returns 10 .I.e def(10) acts as if it is a return statement but it isn't.
The output of the function is always 10 and doesn't lead to undefined behaviour when statement n as given in code isn't present in the code.
I am using sublime text 3.
So why it is behaving in such a manner or am I missing any concept

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int def(int x){
    return x;
}
int abc(int x){
    def(10);
    return x;//statement: n
}
int main(){
    cout<<abc(5);
}
```

Comment: not returning something in a function that is declared to return something is undefined behavior. The boring truth is: If you remove that statement your code is invalid and compiling it can result in anything

Comment: TL;DR: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: to get 10 as output, you need to call  return def(10), instead of return x in func abc

Comment: but the code always give answer as 10 and doesn't give an error please try it with your system

Comment: the code as posted prints 5 not 10 (https://godbolt.org/z/se6EMb) without that line it can print anything. 42 would be a completely valid output and you won't get errors. Turn on warnings and read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: yeah it prints 5 with statement n but without it ,it gives 10 as output

Comment: it prints 10 because the code is invalid in that case. Compilers are not made to compile invalid code. If you still ask them to do so the result can be anything